# How to bind a ComboBox to generic dictionary with xaml code

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, data-binding

I'm using the following code  :

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GetNumber { get; set; }
public ReportsLetterTra()
{
    GetNumber = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                {"1", "First"},
                                {"2", "Second"}
                            };

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

xaml code :

```
 <ComboBox 
      DisplayMemberPath="value" 
      SelectedValuePath="key" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=reportslettra,Path=GetNumber}"
      SelectedIndex="0" Name="cmbFromNumber" />
```

Why is not bind GetNumber to cmbFromNumber?!

**Update :**

my complete code in behind file :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication20
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetNumber { get; set; }

        public Window1()
        {

            GetNumber = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                    {
                                        {"1", "First"},
                                        {"2", "Second"}
                                    };
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

my complete xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication20.Window1" Name="eportslettra"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Height="26">
        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=reportslettra,Path=GetNumber}" 
               SelectedIndex="0"  Name="cmbFromNumber"    />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Where is my wrong?
Why is not bind GetNumber to cmbFromNumber?!

Comment: you need to set your DataContext of your window to an instance for databinding to work. you can do this in the constructor with `this.DataContext = this;` since you are locally binding in the window. You should also check your output window when you databind, you can see some small details on why the databinding is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is marked as `private`, make it `public`. Also, correct the casing on your `ComboBox` to `Value` and `Key`. Thirdly, your binding expression looks invalid, double check this. Finally, it looks like your properties are part of the view's code behind file. You might consider the MVVM design pattern.

**Update**

Your `Window` has the `Name` of 'eportslettra', but your binding expression uses the `ElementName` 'reportslettra'. Correct one of them.

Comment: i'm use :    public Dictionary<string, string> GetNumber { get; set; }. but Not displayed data in combobox. why ?